# Internet does not work via pppoeconf after Ubuntu upgrading from 15.04 to 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, pppoe

Before upgrading Ubuntu 15.04 x64 to 15.10 internet was working fine via pppoeconf, username and password. But now it does not work and I can't see any information about eth0 due pppoeconf processing. It created some connection for enp5s0 but not for eth0 and it does not work. I have the same problem in trying mode . I have the same problem in Kubuntu 15.10 . What do I have to do?
My laptop is Asus G74Sx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in default route. Try to add default route by

```
sudo route add default ppp0
```

Comment: Did not help for me